# Probabilistic gold standard vs Deterministic gold standard

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, data-mining, supervised-learning

I understand that we say something as a gold standard when it involves human intervention/judgement/review.

But can someone help me understand what's the difference between probabilistic gold standard and deterministic gold standard.

For ex: Patient has cancer or not - binary response - Deterministic gold standard which can be provided by humans.

Whereas Patient has 60% chance of being a cancer and 40% chance of not being a cancer. Am I right to understand that this is called as probabilistic gold standard but this can't be produced by Humans right?

Can any human/doctor for example, say this patient has 60% chance of being a cancer and 40 % chance of not  being a cancer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, deterministic probability is when you know for certain. If a person does not have a diagnosis, then he doesn't have the disease/condition. Doctors are not supposed to give a probability but we as human beings always like to know the likelihood.

For example, person A who is 27 years old who has the coronavirus is highly unlikely to die of the virus but it's not impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upvoted

Comment: can there by gold standards in probabilities?

Comment: Yes, for example, if you toss a coin, then the probability of it landing on either heads or tails is definitely 0.5, that's the gold standard. In health care related stuff, a person who has a flu will definitely have a cold but not the vice versa.